# How to evenly space <li> item in a nav bar using Flexbox? HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple nav bar for a portfolio site. My HTML and CSS is below. I can not figure out how to evenly space the '''li''' item evenly.  I can't apply justifiy-content:space-evenly to the UL because the same code is being applied to the '''div class="headerContainer'''

```css
.headerContainer {
    display: flex;
    background-color: lightblue;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;

}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="headerContainer">
        <div class="logo">Robert Emmet</div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.headerContainer {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}



nav {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="headerContainer">
    <div class="logo">Robert Emmet</div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Hey thank you, that is what i was looking for. I guess i needed to add the width back to the NAV element??

Comment: Yes, it is needed. Please upvote this answer and select the gray checkmark to mark it as solved.